# Merging two MACRO scripts (WORD)

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have two Macro scripts, both are working perfectly individually! But I want to marge them and have 1 script.
Basically, I want to save all pages in a WORD document (like 100 pages) as PDF and name each file according to the 3rd line of each page.
So first script is the following which converts to PDF:

```
Sub SaveAsSeparatePDFs()

Dim strDirectory As String, strTemp As String, ipgEnd As Integer
Dim iPDFnum As Integer, i As Integer

strTemp = InputBox("How many pages is included?" & vbNewLine & "(ex: 60)")
ipgEnd = CInt(strTemp)
strDirectory = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop"
        
iPDFnum = 1
For i = 1 To ipgEnd
    
    ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _
        strDirectory & "\User--" & iPDFnum & FirstPara & ".pdf", ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, _
        OpenAfterExport:=False, OptimizeFor:=wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:= _
        wdExportFromTo, From:=i, To:=i + 1, Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, _
        IncludeDocProps:=False, KeepIRM:=False, CreateBookmarks:= _
        wdExportCreateHeadingBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, _
        BitmapMissingFonts:=False, UseISO19005_1:=False
    iPDFnum = iPDFnum + 1
    
    i = i + 1
Next i
End
End Sub
```

And here is the second script which renames each file according to third line of the WORD doc:

```
Sub SaveAsWordAndRename()

Dim oSection As Section
Dim r As Range
Dim TempDoc As Document
Dim FirstPara As String

Dim strDirectory As String, strTemp As String, ipgEnd As Integer
Dim iPDFnum As Integer, i As Integer

For Each oSection In ActiveDocument.Sections
Set r = oSection.Range
r.End = r.End - 1
Set TempDoc = Documents.Add
With TempDoc
.Range = r
FirstPara = r.Paragraphs(3).Range.Text
FirstPara = Left(FirstPara, Len(FirstPara) - 1)
.SaveAs FileName:=FirstPara & ".doc"
.Close
End With
Set r = Nothing
Set TempDoc = Nothing
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Since you're apparently trying to split a document generated via a mailmerge, see *Split Merged Output to Separate Documents* or, better still, *Send Mailmerge Output to Individual Files* in the **Mailmerge Tips and Tricks** thread at: https://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/21803-mailmerge-tips-tricks.html. I note too, this is the third time you'posted essentially the same question - you deleted the one you posted yesterday after I replied...

Comment: Cross-posted at: http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?68396-Merging-two-MACRO-scripts-(WORD). For cross-posting etiquette, please read: http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184.